# Existing archive not getting deleted

Tags: powershell

I have to delete the existing archived zip folder when my script re-runs. But it is not doing so. I believe it is because I am appending time-stamp to it.

I want to delete the existing archived folder without considering time-stamp. Archived zip file should get deleted whenever I run it again.

I am using the below code:

```
$source= Get-ChildItem -Path $outputReportFolder "*ABC*?" -Directory
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
Foreach ($s in $source)
{
    $destination = Join-path -path $outputReportFolder -ChildPath "$($s.name)$TimeStamp.zip"
    If(Test-path $destination) {Remove-item $destination}
    [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($s.fullname, $destination)
}
```

Comment: How `$TimeStamp` is defined? Is it different for each invocation of your script?

Answer (score 0):

If `$TimeStamp` is different each time you call the script, then your code will not be able to find older files (created with different `$TimeStamp` value), you probably want something like

```
Remove-Item "$outputReportFolder\$($s.name)*.zip"
```

instead of

```
If(Test-path $destination) {Remove-item $destination}
```

Keep in mind, it will remove all zip files that match the mask.